# Forget string deduction

Tags: powershell, substring

I am not sure I am phrasing this correctly so I'd rather show.

I am trimming a string in this way:

```
$input = '12345'

$string = $input.Substring(1,$string.Length-1)
```

The idea is to remove the first and the final character. It works fine on the first run. On the second run the length is already -1 so two characters are actually trimmed.

However I want the script to always deduct the final character (5) even after the first run. How do I reset it ?

Thank you.

Comment: Don't use `$input` as self-defined variable, because it is an [Automatic variable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_automatic_variables?view=powershell-7#input) in PowerShell

Comment: Shouldn't `$string.Length-1` be `$input.Length-1`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The second parameter of Substring is the *length* of the substring, not the ending index. Hence you want the string to be 2 characters shorter:

```bsh
$inputstring = "12345"
$string = $inputstring
while ($string.Length -gt 2)
{
    $string
    $string = $string.Substring(1,$string.Length-2)
}
$string
```

This outputs:

```
12345
234
3
```